# How to fix this unmanaged dll security access issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, com

Someone ask a question here
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t89847-asp-net-unmanaged-dll-security-issues.html

and nobody seems to know. Does someone here knows better ?

Comment: You will have a much better chance of getting an answer if you don't force people to go to a different site just to see what you are asking. Why not repost the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you don't have reflection permissions in your web app. try to run your web app in full trust.

Post your problem and code here for better responses.

Comment: I don't have any real need at the moment I just asked for future need :)